Is there a way to make the Least Cost Path lines in ArcGIS Pro thicker?
I'm currently running Least Cost Path analysis in ArcGIS Pro. I found that the Least Cost Paths (lines that represent the most cost-efficient way to travel between different locations) are extremely thin and almost invisible without zooming in. Is there a way to make these lines thicker in ArcGIS Pro or other software?
It seems that things like Adobe Illustrator do not work because the image exported from ArcGIS Pro does not have different elements in layers. So the lines cannot be selected and thickened.

What format is the exported image in?
